# Dockerize a scala app: Could not find or load main class

Tags: scala, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to understand how to compile and run a scala app with Docker and I followed this example : https://github.com/codefresh-contrib/scala-hello-world-app

my project looks like:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   └── plugins.sbt
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
            └── HelloWorld.scala
```

HelloWorld is simple:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

build.properties reads:

```
sbt.version=1.3.8
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "scala-hello-world-sample-app"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
```

and finally my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9 

WORKDIR /HelloWorld

COPY . /HelloWorld

CMD ["java", "-cp", "target/scala-2.12/*.jar:scala-library-2.12.2.jar", "HelloWorld"]
```

Yet I cannot seem to make it work, I execute the two next commands where the Dockerfile is:

```
docker build -t my_image .
```

but `docker run my_image` yields:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

PS: the output of `docker build -t my_image .` is:

```
+] Building 2.7s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9                                                                                                        2.6s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9@sha256:f362b165b870ef129cbe730f29065ff37399c0aa8bcab3e44b51c302938c9193                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => => transferring context: 7.36kB                                                                                                                                               0.1s
 => CACHED [2/3] WORKDIR /HelloWorld                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [3/3] COPY . /HelloWorld                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:f9b47f877daa755c569a34bac4b24d6f08b55746a5df24d605fe9878ab124822                                                                                      0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/my_image
```

Comment: You probably need to run a command like `sbt package` before running `docker build` - Also, I personally would use the [**sbt-assembly** plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and use the command `sbt assembly` instead, that way you only need to copy a single JAR instead of multiple ones and you would not need to change the docker file when you change the scala version _(except for major versions)_, this also will help when you start adding libraries. Also, if you have an app with a single main then you can just use `CMD ["java", "-server", "-jar", "app.jar"]`.

Comment: Finally, you may find the [**sbt-native-packager** plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) plus its **Docker** module more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in `plugins.sbt`

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1")
```

run

```scala
sbt clean compile dist
```

then you will found a zipFile in `./target/universal`
create Dockerfile like this

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./ /opt
WORKDIR /opt
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/your-app"]
```

there you go